# Lifecycle of a Service and the best way to unregister Listeners

Tags: android, service, android-appwidget

I've an IntentService which updates an AppWidget. That Service starts every time the AppWidget is being placed on the Screen or when the AlarmManager /ContentObserver / OnChangeListener get called. It stops itself after updating the widget.

```
UpdateService.java:
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    contentObserver = new CustomContentObserver();
    registerContentObserver(contentObserver);

    /* Am I registering several instances here or is this fine? */

    onChangeListener = new CustomSharedPreferencesOnChangeListener();
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onChangeListener);

    Intent updateIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateService.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, updateIntent, 0);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    if(AppWidget.DISABLE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        unregisterContentObserver(contentObserver); 
        sharedPreferences.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(onChangeListener);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    } else {
        /* Scheduling next update */
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextUpdateTime, pendingIntent);

        /* Updating the Widget ... */
        updateWidget();

        /* Stopping the Service */
        stopSelf();
    }
}
```

The service shouldn't start when there is no widget to update, so I have to unregister the listener and observer and cancel the pending intent.

I am wondering what the best way is to clean up the resources? Starting the service to stop it seems a bit awkward to me.

```
AppWidget.java:
@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, UpdateService.class);
    intent.setAction(DISABLE);
    context.startService(intent);
    context.stopService(intent);
    super.onDisabled(context);
}
```

I am also wondering about the costs of starting and stopping a service. Would it be better to let the Service run all the time and clean up in onDestroy() when the last widget is removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never register a listener in an `IntentService`, just as you never register a listener in a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`. These are supposed to be short-lived objects. Your listeners are keeping your defunct `IntentService` in memory and are leaking memory along the way.

> Would it be better to let the Service
>   run all the time and clean up in
>   onDestroy() when the last widget is
>   removed?

User get very irritated when applications keep services running all the time, unless they clearly understand the benefit. I would avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So is it better to register the ChangeListener when the PreferenceScreen opens to send an updateIntent every time preferences change?
Where would you register the ContentObserver?

Comment: @konradf: "So is it better to register the ChangeListener when the PreferenceScreen opens to send an updateIntent every time preferences change?" -- that should work AFAIK. "Where would you register the ContentObserver?" -- I wouldn't. It doesn't do you any good. Update the widget per your timer -- you do not need a `ContentObserver` for that. If you want, send an update to the widget from whatever is updating the content that you are trying to observe.

Comment: @CommonsWare What then would be the best way to manage a background observer, if not inside a background service? I want an observer to be alive as long as the system is alive.

Comment: @Olayinka: I do not know what sort of observer you are referring to. Usually, you want to be driven by events (broadcasts, `AlarmManager`, etc.). "I want an observer to be alive as long as the system is alive" -- then build your own device or custom ROM, as Android users can get rid of your service whenever they want to. You will need to create a standard Linux daemon, so it is not something that users manage directly. You can take steps (foreground services, `START_STICKY`, etc.) to try to live for a long time, but you cannot live forever.

Comment: @CommonsWare Of course I'm aware of the user's and system's abilities to kill off the service but then I can always restart it with Alarm, Boot, START_STICKY but the problem is this service needs to register an observer.

Comment: @Olayinka: Again, I do not know what sort of observer you are referring to and what this has to do with this answer. My notes about listeners are referring to `IntentService`, not `Service`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using an `IntentService` and a `ContactObserver`.

Comment: @Olayinka: Since there is no `ContactObserver` in the Android SDK, I do not know what you are referring to. But your process can go away once the `IntentService` finishes `onHandleIntent()`, and so if you want a durable service, use `Service` and fork your own thread(s).

Comment: @CommonsWare That was a typo, I meant `ContentObserver` but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Olayinka: Yes, for a durable `ContentObserver`, use a `Service` and fork your own thread(s). The downside of `ContentObserver` is that AFAIK, it only delivers results on the main application thread, so you'd need to determine how best to get your significant work off of that thread and onto a background thread.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your time. I will do a trial and error on this approach and see if I can get a good result.